# ExtJS 4: Why don't fields appear in my custom Ext.form.Panel?

Tags: extjs4

I'm defining a class that extends Ext.form.Panel but none of the fields appear when it's shown (they're not even in the DOM). Is there something wrong with defining the class this way?

```js
Ext.define('myapp.view.admin.EditUserFormPanel', {    
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    requires: [
        'myapp.util.Logger'
    ],

    /**
     * Constructor, typically used to create any instance variables and declare
     * the events that this object may fire (if it is Observable). For more info
     * see http://goo.gl/rXpzO
     *
     * @param {Object} config (optional)
     */
    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this; // http://goo.gl/QYYZm
        config = config || {};

        Log.info('Created '+me.self.getName());

        // Call the method we are overriding (i.e., the parent's constructor),
        // passing in all arguments that we have received via JavaScript's
        // standard "arguments" object.
        me.callParent(arguments);

        // Apply default config settings
        me.initConfig(config);

        me.items = [
            {
                type: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'OpenID',
                name: 'openid'
            },
            {
                type: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'First',
                name: 'firstName'
            },
            {
                type: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Last',
                name: 'lastName'
            },
            {
                type: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'email'
            }
        ];

        return me;
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: How are you instantiating the class in the app?

Comment: tabPanel.add( Ext.create('myapp.view.admin.EditUserFormPanel') );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For views (visible components) (More detailed: everything that inherits from Ext.Component)  you should use `initComponent` instead of `constructor` to set up your component.

Just replace the word `constructor` with `initComponent` in your example and it should work.

[See the API for details on the initComponent method.](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-initComponent)

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, I also needed to take @dougajmcdonald's advice and switch from type: 'textfield' to xtype:'textfield'

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to use `xtype: 'textfield'` rather than `type: textfield`

Comment: Thanks Doug! You and suknic were both correct--wish I could mark both as answers.